# Adding Bing or Google imagery to the standard web application code derived from Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am new to Geoserver. I know how to add layers to geoserver and view them using openlayers. Then i do a ctrl+U and copy the code into a html file which i place into my www folder in Geoserver. When i open this html file on the browser it works fine.
My problem is….
I want to add bing imagery or google imagery to this code, i am unable to make it work. 
I have managed to use Bing imagery on a separate openlayers code, but, I am unable to integrate it with the code i copied from Geoserver. Do you have any tips on this?
I am not pasting my Geoserver code in this message because it is very long, and it is the standard code that one gets on pressing ctrl+U on the keyboard, when doing a layer preview in Geoserver.

Answer (score 1):

You will need several things :

- Firstly you will need the full version of OpenLayers. The version of OpenLayers that comes with geoserver is a lite version,  ment just for preview.
- Then you need to properly build the app. Just randomly copy pasting code Without understanding will lead you nowhere. There are a [few examples](http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/) on the OpenLayers site which will be useful. Specifically look for the overlay examples, where they are overlaying WMS layers on top of Google Maps.
- There are [several question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5BOpenLayers%5D%20Overlay%20WMS%20is:question) on this site which also talk about overlaying WMS Layers on top of Base maps. You could go through them to understand better.

Comment: Thanks Devdatta, I have added the entire version of OpenLayers, and i have edited the original code that i got from Geoserver, i changed much of the Javascript to JQuery, my app works. What i meant by when i said that i have used the dafault code is that all the elements are same as default as i have not added anything fancy yet. I shall do more research online on how to add the google API or Bing maps API. Thanks for your response.